# Explaining the phrase 目がくっきり

Tags: meaning, usage

I found an article [here](http://www.excite.co.jp/News/weather/20160706/Tenkijp_7261.html), and it's title starts with the phrase 目がくっきり. How to translate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「[目]{め}が**くっきり**としていて、～～」
>
> = "the (typhoon's) eye looks ***sharp and clear***, and ~~"

「くっきり」 means "sharp-looking", "clear-looking", etc.

In the given context, 「目」 refers to 「[台風]{たいふう}の目」 ("the eye of a typhoon"), and in this case, the eye looks very sharp and clear.  We just refer to the center of a typhoon as 台風の目.

「～～**と**している」 is a common phrase describing a characteristic of a thing.

「くっきり」 is also often used to describe human eyes as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We say the center of the typhoon as 台風の目(eye of typhoon) because it looks like eye.

The clearer the eye show the stronger the stream is. How about "the eye of typhoon shows clearly"?

Answer (score 2):

Distinctly Visible Eye

Later in the article they say 目がくっきりしていて, "(the hurricane's) eye is distinctly visible."

If you look up くっきり at eg jisho.org,you will see entries like clear, sharp, distinct relating to vision, especially contrast/clarity.

In other words, the title and article focus on how much the eye stands out relative to the hurricane, and what that means in terms of the hurricane's winds.